# Create Facebook store application: where should I start?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I've never built a Facebook app. All I've done so far is registering my FB account as a developer in https://developers.facebook.com and I saw there are LOADS of tutorials and docs there so it's a bit overwhelming. So I'm looking for some advice on what to read and what to learn (if needed).

I'd like to build an app that adds a "shop" tab on facebook pages, where the user can list their products and add a price, description, etc for it. There should be a shopping cart where the user can check out and be taken to a payment section where I'll integrate it with https://developers.mercadopago.com to generate a payment ticket the user can use to pay. They allow php, .NET, Node.js, Ruby and Python, but I only know a bit of php, .NET and python, so those would be my options to choose from.

Any advice is welcome :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read their PHP "Getting Started" guide. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

The Getting Started guides for all APIs are linked from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ — I would probably check JS next, but you can go your own way from there.